# cron stop sending error mails if command output is redirected to logfile

Tags: linux, cron, postfix-mta

I have a problem with the error mail's from cron
If I create two job's executing the same perl script one which redirected to /dev/null or a logfile and one without redirect I only get an error mail for the one without redirect

```
/etc/cron.d/test-cron

MAILTO="logs@example.com"
*   *   *   *   *   root    /root/test.sh > /dev/null
*   *   *   *   *   root    /root/test.sh
```

```
/root/test.sh

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

print "test\n";
exit 1;
```

syslog output for cron and postfix

```
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master CRON[31428]: (root) CMD ([31436] /root/test.sh)
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master CRON[31428]: (CRON) error (grandchild #31436 failed with exit status 1)
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master CRON[31428]: (root) END ([31436] /root/test.sh)
```

```
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master CRON[31429]: (root) CMD ([31439] /root/test.sh > /dev/null)
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master CRON[31429]: (CRON) error (grandchild #31439 failed with exit status 1)
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master CRON[31429]: (root) END ([31439] /root/test.sh > /dev/null)
```

```
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master postfix/pickup[28859]: 5537251A9: uid=0 from=<root>
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master postfix/cleanup[30966]: 5537251A9: message-id=<20200518191401.5537251A9@cron-master@example.com>
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master postfix/qmgr[143]: 5537251A9: from=<cron-master@example.com>, size=674, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master postfix/smtp[30968]: 5537251A9: to=<logs@example.com>, relay=smtp.example.com[80.50.67.97]:587, delay=0.42, delays=0.02/0/0.32/0.09, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Requested mail action okay, completed: id=1Ma1oK-1jXP8H2tyW-00W08q)
May 18 19:14:01 cron-master postfix/qmgr[143]: 5537251A9: removed
```

- cron -> 3.0pl1-136ubuntu1
- postfix -> 3.4.10-1ubuntu1
- OS -> latest Ubuntu 20.04 docker image (ubuntu:focal-20200423)
- Docker Endpoint -> /usr/sbin/cron -f -l -L 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tee` command to "fork" standard output.

```
*   *   *   *   *   root    /root/test.sh | tee -a logfile_name
```

---

[man tee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee)

> tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
>   **Synopsis**
>   tee [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>   **Description**
>   Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.
>
> -a, --append
>      append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite

Comment: many thanks this is working also with  
```*   *   *   *   *   root    /root/test.sh 2>&1 | tee -a logfile_name```
to capture error's